# ffmpeg can't read png data on iphone

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, opengl-es, ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg to decode a png picture and use the AVFrame as a opengl texture.
But the strangest thing is that I can get the png converted to opengl texture nicely on a iphone simulator, but I got a blank texture on a real iphone.

on both simulator and iphone, I got a null pointer for AVFrame's data

```
avcodec_decode_video2(codecContext/* AVCodecContext* */,frame /* AVFrame */,&finished,&tempPacket);
```

Then I covert the color space to AV_PIX_FMT_RGBA

```
void convertToRGBColor()
{
    int numBytes = avpicture_get_size(
                                  AV_PIX_FMT_RGBA,
                                  codecContext->width,
                                  codecContext->height);
    uint8_t *buffer = (uint8_t *)av_malloc(numBytes);
    avpicture_fill(rgbFrame/* AVFrame* */, buffer, AV_PIX_FMT_RGBA, codecContext->width, codecContext->height);

    struct SwsContext *img_convert_ctx = NULL;
    img_convert_ctx = sws_getCachedContext(
                         img_convert_ctx,
                         codecContext->width,
                         codecContext->height,
                         codecContext->pix_fmt,
                         codecContext->width,
                         codecContext->height,
                         COLOR_SPACE,
                         SWS_BILINEAR,
                         NULL,
                         NULL,
                         NULL);

    if( !img_convert_ctx )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot initialize sws conversion context\n");
    }

    sws_scale(img_convert_ctx,
              frame->data,
              frame->linesize,
              0,
              codecContext->height,
              rgbFrame->data,
              rgbFrame->linesize);
    sws_freeContext(img_convert_ctx);
}
```

On a simulator, rgbFrame's data[0] will be a valid pointer, but on a iphone, it's null.

So, does anyone had the same problem before?